# How to create blur tab navigation bar in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
  return (
    <VibrancyView
      style={[styles.container, styles.blurViewStyle]}
      blurAmount={24}
      reducedTransparencyFallbackColor="transparent"
      blurType="dark">
      <NavigationIcon type={NavigationIcons.PAYMENTS} />
      <NavigationIcon isActive type={NavigationIcons.WALLET} />
      <NavigationIcon type={NavigationIcons.PROFILE} />
    </VibrancyView>
  );
```

**Style**

```
    container: {
      height: 84,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
      borderTopColor: 'grey',
      borderStyle: 'solid',
      borderTopWidth: 0.5,
    },
    blurViewStyle: {
      position: 'absolute',
      left: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      right: 0,
    },
```

I want to create tab navigation bar which have some blur effect something similar to these https://github.com/alex-melnyk/translucent-tabbar/blob/master/PREVIEW.gif

I am using @react-native-community/blur this library but unable to create the same.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note that VibrancyView is only supported on iOS. I would recommend you to use BlurView instead like this:

```
<Image
    key={'blurryImage'}
    source={{ uri }}
    style={styles.absolute}
    />
        <Text style={styles.absolute}>Hi, I am some blurred text</Text>
        <BlurView
          style={styles.absolute}
          blurType="light"
          blurAmount={10}
          reducedTransparencyFallbackColor="white"
        />
        <Text>I'm the non blurred text because I got rendered on top of BlurView</Text>
```

Note that everything before the "BlurryView" tag, everything is blured.